# Export bigQuery table to google data storage runs into AttributeError exception

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-python-api

I am trying to export table from google bigQuery to google data storage as json file.

Running this python snippet

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()
bucket_name = 'mybucket'

destination_uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, 'myfile.json')
dataset_ref = client.dataset('mydataset')
table_ref = dataset_ref.table('mytable')
job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
job_config.destination_format = (
    bigquery.DestinationFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON)

extract_job = client.extract_table(
    table_ref, destination_uri, job_config=job_config
    )
extract_job.result()
```

I received this error

```
AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.bigquery' has no attribute 'DestinationFormat'
```

I followed the official documentation 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#configuring_export_options

Here my python packages version

- google-api-core (1.1.0)
- google-auth (1.4.1)
- google-cloud-bigquery (0.31.0)
- google-cloud-core (0.28.1)
- google-resumable-media (0.3.1)
- googleapis-common-protos (1.5.3)

How is it possible to receive this error with the latest packages / documentation ?

Thank you in advance for your help
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Can you try replacing `bigquery.DestinationFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON` with `bigquery.job.DestinationFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON`?. It is probably a bug in the documentation.

Comment: Not exactly a bug, more that the sample was republished before a release of the libraries. This constant was added to the `bigquery` module in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/pull/4987

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the version installed locally has the required attribute, maybe you have an older version : open Python console, import bigquery, and dir it or help(bq) or such to see that the attribute is there. If it isn't, pip update the gcloud package and try again.

If from the Python shell the attribute is actually there, but it's not when you run the script, then there must be a second version of Python installed.

There may be other causes but let's see what you find.